# Get files with no specific word in the name using Directory.GetFiles

Tags: c#, regex

I need to get all files that don't contain upload word in them. Here's what I've tried but it didn't work.

```
string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\Reports", @"*[^upload].xls")
foreach (string file in fileList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [**`GetFiles`** documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx):

> `searchPattern`
>   `Type: System.String`
>   **The search string** to match against the names of files in path. This parameter can contain a combination of valid literal path and wildcard (`*` and `?`) characters (see Remarks), but **doesn't support regular expressions**.

Here is my suggestion that can get all Excel files, not just those old Excel *.xls files and then I am using `Contains` to filter out unwanted entries:

```
var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\Reports", @"*.xls*")
foreach (var file in fileList)
{
    if (!file.ToLower().Contains("upload".ToLower()))
        Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/a4w8uM)

In case you need to filter out ONLY the files with `upload` and NOT `uploading`, you can use `Regex`:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(file, @"(?i)\bupload\b"))
```

Where `\b` stands for a word boundary, and `(?i)` for case-insensitive matching.

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/IhGFX2) (only the file name with `upload` was filtered out, the one with `uploading` remains)

Comment: Do you want to exclude files that have `upload` as whole word? Or "uploading" is also a no-go?

Comment: I need to exclude files that have only upload as whole word

Answer (score 1):

[`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't support regular expressions. Instead you can use `Linq` `Where` method to filter the results, example:

```
string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\Reports", @"*.xls");
foreach (string file in fileList.Where(f => !f.Contains("upload"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[^upload]` is a negated character class and will match anything except the characters within character class. Instead you can use a [negative look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!upload)`.

Check the @Avinash Raj's answer for complete regex.